# Обновление обработчика

Tags: jquery

Есть много новостей. С помощью функции `.on()` вешаю свою функцию на все ссылки в этой новости.

Все хорошо, но до того момента, пока я не подгружу новую новость через **AJAX** — функция которая была повешена на ссылки, перестает работать.

Суть в том, что нужно правильно повесить обработчик на новые ссылки после подгрузки новых новостей — **как?**

Comment: вы добавляете новый контент на страницу, и события добавленные через `.on()` к старому контенту перестают срабатывать? покажите хоть немного кода. В [документации](http://api.jquery.com/on/) есть такой пример:
    
     $("body").on("click", "a", function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
     });

может вам нужно что-то подобное?
В данном случае используется body, вы можете использовать родительский элемент всех новостей, только с условием, что он присутсвует на странице в момент срабатывания скрипта и добавления "новостей"

Comment: @Spectre, подошел вариант который предложил @Sh4dow, но ваш вариант вероятно тоже верный - спасибо за желание помочь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Либо юзать [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/), либо вешать обработчики после загрузки.

```
$.post(
  ...
  function(data) {
    // что-то делаем, получаем el = $('#new-news')
    el.find('a.someClass').on('click', myHandler);
  }
);
```

А если как сказал [[@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre), проверьте, чтобы в подгружаемой новости не было скрипта, перезаписывающего функцию. Еще могут быть аномалии, если контент добавлять не через `.append()`, а `$('news-all').html($('news-all').html()+newHTML);` - у меня в таких случаях часто обнулялись значения input'ов и еще какое-то веселье было, не вспомню.

Comment: `.live()` и `.on()` одинаково делегируют события, дело не в этом

Comment: Да ладно?

    > The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object.

`.live` работает на созданных после объявления элементах, `.on` - нет. В этом смысле `.on` - эквивалент `.bind`.

Comment: мне больше нравится это:

    As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Comment: @Sh4dow, **10K**! Спасибо. Метод `live` сделал своё дело.

Comment: @exec, благодарю) 

@Spectre, у `.on()`, который `.live()`, синтаксис другой. В общем, да, это стоит иметь в виду на jq>1.7.